# Visual Studio '/FC' option is giving the filename in lower case

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor, msdn

I am using the '/FC' option in VisualStudio 2010 to get the full path file name from the **FILE** macro, but the file name is getting traced in lower case.

It is documented in below link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/027c4t2s(v=vs.100).aspx

Is this a expected behaviour or any change in the Project properties can give the FileName correctly instead of filename in total lower case?

Example:
I have the below code in Visual Studio 2010

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void logEvent(const char* const fileName)
{
    cout << "Full path file name:" << fileName << endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    logEvent(__FILE__);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is coded in file name: FileNameTest.cpp

But the output for the above is shown as:

> Full path file name:c:\users\pradp\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\filenam etest\filenametest\filenametest.cpp

AS you can see the total filename is traced in lower case

The setting made in the VisualStudio :
Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> UseFullPaths

Comment: sᴍᴀʟʟ ᴄᴀᴘs exist, but you mean lowercase.

Comment: By design, there is no knob to change this behavior.